# how to enable azure blob enumerator in visual studio 2015 or 2017 for sql server 2016 in ssis

Tags: azure, ssis

I dont see azure blob enumerator in visual studio 2017 and 2015 for sql server 2016 for the Business Intelligence project even after downloading the Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services

Comment: Are you seeing any of the Azure tools in the SSIS Toolbox?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean "Foreach Azure Blob Enumerator" in Foreach Loop Container?